# Polymorphism in Web API: Single endpoint possible?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I realize that the Web API is REST focused, but I would still like to configure a single controller method that can handle a Command/Response scenario.  So far I haven't been successful... is there a way to have the following class structure recognized by a single API endpoint?

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Command{
    public int CommandId{get; set;}
}
[Serializable]
public class RegisterNewPersonCommand:Command{
   public string Name{get; set;}
}
//etc... various Command subclasses. Similar thing for Responses.

//now have a single endpoint to Handle Commands
public class CommandsController : ApiController{
   public Response HandleCommand(Command command){
      //handle Command based on which subclass it is
      //return appropriate Response subclass
   }
}
```

Thus far it doesn't seem the serialization system can handle this scenario, but I hope someone out there has found a way to do it :)

Comment: Even if it works, how does this help re-use any code?

Comment: I want to reduce code in my Controller.  Instead of a boilerplate method for each subclass of Command (`HandleNewUserCommand(NewUserCommand){}, HandleUserPasswordChangeCommand(UserPasswordChangeCommand){}', etc), the single `HandleCommand` method will be responsible for using reflection and IoC to pass the Command along to the appropriate domain logic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order for polymorphism to work in Web API, you will need to enable type name handling and the data has to contain the type information.

You'll need to turn on `TypeNameHandling` in `WebApiConfig.cs` if you're using JSON in your scenario:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All;
```

Then, the content body that you are sending to your `HandleCommand(...)` action must contain the type information:

```
{"$type":"MvcApplication.Models.RegisterNewPersonCommand, MvcApplication", ... }
```

For XML, you'll need to use DataContract's KnownType...

By the way, is there any specific reason why you are using `[Serializable]` (since POCO types and `[DataContract]` types are also supported...)?

Comment: This seems to be the right idea.  Is there a way to configure the HttpClient to include the $type info?  In my tests, `var task= client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/commands/handlecommand", testCommand);` does not include the $type information when it serializes to json.

Comment: This answered my question and helped me figure out how to specify formatting on the client end.  For what it's worth, the simplest client code looks something like: `private void SendCommand(Command command){var json = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter {SerializerSettings = {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All}};var response = client.PostAsync("api/commands/handlecommand", command, json).Result;//handle response}`

Comment: This helped me.. The only other thing I had to search all over the internet to find was that Interfaces are not serializable, something I've known forever, but due to all the magic of Json serialization in .Net I seemed to forget:)  So NO ICollection, IEnumerable, instead use List<> etc...  Now I have polymorphic serialization working :)  And now I wonder if I should be flattening my DTO's :p

Comment: `TypeNameHandling.Auto` is nicer because it doesn't write the instance type name when it matches the type of the field/property, which is usually the case for most types.