# Json parameter casting inheritance web api 2

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am using MS Web API 2 to receive calls from our web page using ajax. 
Then I have 2 classes: subscriber and externalSubscriber. Subscriber contains very basic data like a name and id. External subscriber inherits from subscriber and adds basic data like address and email. I have one api method to edit the data of a subscriber defined like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PutSubscriber(int id, Subscriber subscriber)
```

In our page I create a json string using the data provided which leads to it ether being a external or a normal subscriber. 
I am able to post to this function using both but with an externalSubscriber object the added data gets lost and trying to cast from subscriber leads to an error.

my question is if anyone has any experience with this issue and if there is another way to fix this besides creating a specific function for putting a external subscriber.

Comment: Check out [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it to work by using the information provided on the following pages:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm
[Polymorphism in Web API: Single endpoint possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609579/polymorphism-in-web-api-single-endpoint-possible)

First I set the json setting:

```
jsonsettings.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

then setting the type of the json object before sending with ajax using

```
jsonObject { '$type' : .Models.ExternalSubscriber, solution.project', ....}
```

after this I am able to cast the incoming Subscriber to an ExternalSubscriber and access its properties.