# Convert if/else statement to ?: operator C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I would like to reduce my code to something better. That's why I'm trying to convert if/else statement to operator ?:

My actual code looks like this :

```
if (resultat.CodeAlgo != null)
 {
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = resultat.CodeAlgo.ToString();
 }
else
 {
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = string.Empty;
}
```

I tried to convert to :

```
resultat.CodeAlgo != null
  ? worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = resultat.CodeAlgo.ToString()
  : worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = string.Empty;
```

But it said :

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object statement can be used as a statement.

First time I'm using this operator and I don't understand why my simplification is wrong ?

Comment: Ok because Visuel Studio said that it's better to use ?: in my case

Comment: `worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = resultat.CodeAlgo?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;` should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shorthand If Statements: C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073563/shorthand-if-statements-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign result of ternary operation

```
worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = resultat.CodeAlgo != null
                ?  resultat.CodeAlgo.ToString()
                :  string.Empty;
```

or you can use  [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??`,

```
worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = resultat.CodeAlgo?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

---

## Ternary Operator `?:`

Syntax of ternary operator:

```
 output = condition ? expression 1 : expression 2;
```

- If condition is `true` then result of `expression 1` get assigned to `output` variable otherwise `expression 2` will be assigned.

## Null coalescing operator `??` ([From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator))

> operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't
>   null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its
>   result. The ?? operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the
>   left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

## Null conditional operator `?.`

If you notice in second solution, I used `?.` operator, this operator is called as [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). This operator execute only if `resultat.CodeAlgo` is not-null. It will return null if `resultat.CodeAlgo` is null, this will help us to avoid null reference exception.

Answer (score 2):

You assign the value to worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value. so the code should be

```
worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = resultat.CodeAlgo != null ? resultat.CodeAlgo.ToString() : string.Empty;
```