# C# short if statement to execute a function if true

Tags: c#

Is it possible to execute a function within a short statement if the statement is true?

Something like that:

```
myObject.subObject != null ?? Db.LoadReferences(myObject.subObject); // ORMLite function
```

Comment: What about `if (myObject.subObject != null) Db.LoadReferences(myObject.subObject);`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shorthand If Statements: C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073563/shorthand-if-statements-c-sharp)

Comment: Since C# 8: `myObject.subObject ??= Db...`

Comment: @CodeCaster It seems, that OP doesn't need an assignment here

Comment: @Pavel I highly doubt that, because if `myObject.subObject` is null and you pass it to a method without `ref`, the method can't do anything useful with it. Edit: or it's the other way around, then you're right.

Answer (score 2):

yes:

```
if(myObject.subObject != null) Db.LoadReferences(myObject.subObject);
```

At just 1 single character more than your original.

Comment: Mind the possibility to use [` is not null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements) in C# 9